# I'm new to spark,trying to generate the decision tree model in scala and use that model in java to predict.How to load that model in java?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark-mllib

i have saved the model generated in scala to disc.

val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
      impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
    model.save(sc, "C:\Model")

Answer (score 0):

Using same imports for Java in order to load model:

```
DecisionTreeModel model = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc, "C:\\Model");
```